# Who should be invited to which movie?

Tags: stardew-valley

I recently bought the movie theater, and I am trying to find out who should be invited to which movie. For example, I recently invited Leo to Brave Little Sapling, but he only liked it, whereas I know Vincent loves the brave Little Sapling. I already tried to google it, but I only got the answer for Vincent.

Can anyone tell me who likes which movie?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Stardew Valley wiki Movie Theater](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Movie_Theater) page has a breakdown of who loves, likes and dislikes each movie, as well as everyone's favorite snacks. Here's a abridged version of everyone's top choices.

| Villager | Favorite Movie(s) |
| --- | --- |
| Abigail | Mysterium It Howls In The Rain |
| Alex | Wumbus It Howls In The Rain |
| Caroline | The Brave Little Sappling Journey Of The Prairie King: The Motion Picture |
| Demetrius | Natural Wonders: Exploring Our Vibrant World Wumbus |
| Dwarf | Loves all the movies |
| Elliott | Mysterium |
| Emily | The Miracle At Coldstar Ranch |
| Evelyn | The Miracle At Coldstar Ranch The Zuzu City Express |
| George | The Zuzu City Express |
| Gus | The Miracle At Coldstar Ranch Wumbus |
| Haley | Does not love any movie, likes every movie except Journey Of The Prairie King and Wumbus |
| Harvey | The Miracle At Coldstar Ranch The Zuzu City Express |
| Jas | The Brave Little Sapling Journey Of The Prairie King: The Motion Picture Natural Wonders: Exploring Our Vibrant World Wumbus |
| Jodi | The Zuzu City Express |
| Krobus | Does not love any movie, and only likes Mysterium |
| Leah | Mysterium |
| Leo | Natural Wonders: Exploring Our Vibrant World |
| Lewis | Natural Wonders: Exploring Our Vibrant World |
| Marnie | The Miracle At Coldstar Ranch |
| Maru | Natural Wonders: Exploring Our Vibrant World Wumbus |
| Penny | The Brave Little Sapling |
| Pierre | Wumbus |
| Robin | Journey Of The Prairie King: The Motion Picture |
| Sandy | Loves every movie |
| Sam | Wumbus |
| Sebastian | Mysterium It Howls In The Rain |
| Shane | Wumbus It Howls In The Rain |
| Vincent | The Brave Little Sapling Journey Of The Prairie King: The Motion Picture Wumbus |
| Wizard | Mysterium |

Comment: Haley seems to be picky!